# How to fill web form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, console, fill

I want to fill the form data using javascript in chrome. I have filled all other fields correctly but the field(html) bellow is not working for me. (there must be other scripts working this form, i don't about that)

```
<select name="month" class="valid">
<option value="">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Month</font>
    </font>
</option>
<option value="01">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">January</font>
    </font>
</option>
<option value="02">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">February</font>
    </font>
</option>
<option value="03">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">March</font>
    </font>
</option>
```

Month
        
    
    
        January
        
    
    
        
            February
        
    
    
        March

i have tried some code but it doesn't work.

```
var month = document.querySelector('input[name="month"]');
month.selectedIndex = 3;
```

i am using this script in chrome console, is there any way i can fill this field with javascript?

[here is the form link](https://profil.tlen.pl/rejestracja/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does exactly what you looking for. It selects March in your select. 
Note: correct selection in not var month = document.querySelector('input[name="month"]'); Use instead

```
var month = document.querySelector('select[name="month"]');
```

```js
$(function() {
    var month = document.querySelector('select[name="month"]');
month.selectedIndex = 3;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" class="valid">
<option value="">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Month</font>
    </font>
</option>
<option value="01">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">January</font>
    </font>
</option>
<option value="02">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">February</font>
    </font>
</option>
<option value="03">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">March</font>
    </font>
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i am so f**king dumb *crying emoji*... i spend about 4 hours for just trying different options... but how can be i so dumb that i did't look at the selector :'(... thank you so much Sir you are awesome

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-) . Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

First, your selector `input[name="month"]` does not match any elements.

Secondly, once you are able to select the correct element you can set it's value using `element.value = 3`.

[See more about the value property here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp)

Comment: By `input[name="month"]` i am selecting the select element so i can change it's value by assigning the options value. please check this code ( `var month = document.querySelector('input[name="month"]');
  var option = document.getElementsByTagName("option");  
  month.value = option[4].value;`) this is also showing error  (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at <anonymous>:3:15)